# Graphics Diagnostics engine failed to build shader trace in VS2013

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, shader, directx-11

I am using Windows 8, Visual studio 2013, Directx 11.

I run into this error "**This Graphics Diagnostics engine failed to build shader trace and therefore it is unable to debug shader**" while trying to debug shaders using Graphics Diagnostics in Visual Studio 2013.

My program is a rain particle system, which includes two main steps.

1. Update rain particles using computer shader into a structured buffer<[RainParticle]>
2. In CPU side, I using the function `DeviceContext::CopyResource` to copy rain particle from structured buffer above to vertex buffer for rendering.

   I used the function: `Draw(vertexCount, 0)` to render to render target.

The problem come out when I debug shaders in the pipeline of the `Draw` function.
I hope to see your opinion about it!

Comment: Check if your shader is built with debug information

Comment: @Drop: I checked the configuration of the project, and it is in Debug mode. How can check the compile mode of the shader?